# Installing (and soldering to) PTFE (teflon) Insulated Terminals

Tags: soldering, dielectric, terminal

I am doing a condenser microphone board project. Now I need to install two PTFE insulated terminals (these are in the picture) to a board. The holes are a little larger than the bushing of the terminals.

**The question 1.** How can I make the terminals stick inside the hole?  Do I need to use some glue or maybe rivet over the short ends of the pins?

[image: board with standoffs]

**The question 2.** Is it OK to solder some of the components to the short end of the pin?

Comment: The mounting hole should be slightly smaller diameter than the teflon insulator, so the thing has to pressed into the hole, and will be held by friction.  It should be OK to solder to either end of the pin.

Comment: If they are a loose fit, adding a small amount of solder to the inside of the holes would make the pins a tight fit. I have not had any experience with gluing teflon, but it does have a reputation.